# How to add multiple namespaces into IEdmModel in OData service

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api

Currently i am working with OData with WebApi and i have stuck on adding multiple namespace into `IEdmModel GetModel()`in WebApiConfig file. Below is the method i am currently using

```
public static IEdmModel GetModel()
        {
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

           var product= builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
            //product.EntityType.HasKey(pkg => pkg.ID);
            //product.EntityType.HasKey(pkg => pkg.Code);

            builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
            builder.EntitySet<CustomerAddress>("CustomerAddresses");
            builder.EntitySet<CustomerEmail>("CustomerEmails");
            builder.EntitySet<CustomerPhone>("CustomerPhones");
            builder.EntitySet<Country>("Countries");
            builder.EntitySet<State>("States");
            builder.EntitySet<CustomerStore>("CustomerStores");

            builder.Namespace = "StateService";
            builder.EntityType<State>().Collection.Function("GetStatesByCountry").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<State>("States");

            builder.Namespace = "ProductCategoryService";
            builder.EntityType<ProductCategory>().Collection.Function("GetProductCategories").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ProductCategory>("ProductCategories");


            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

If i add another namespace first one will override

```
 builder.Namespace = "StateService";
builder.Namespace = "ProductCategoryService";
```

My problem is is there a any approach to avoid this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please expand on how you solved this? I am trying your accepted answer but can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebAPI OData can set namespace for each entityType, complexType, For example:

```
// Set the default namespace 
builder.Namespace = "Default";
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

var prodType = builder.EntityType<Product>();
// Set the namespace for type product
prodType.Namespace = "ProductNamespace";
```

Comment: this did not work for me - can you provide the full example?

Comment: I am trying to implement this but failing terribly. How does this work?